# Facebook scores api - " Method allowed only for games" error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to run this request on Graph Explorer
me/scores?score=300&access_token=APP_TOKEN with post function.

and the error I get is

```
{
"error": {
"message": "(#3) Method allowed only for games", 
"type": "OAuthException", 
"code": 3
}
}
```

The app is categorized as a Game.

publish_actions permission is granted from the user.

Any clue on this one?

Comment: Did you select your Game App from the pulldown in the Graph Explorer?

Comment: Write an answer, I will accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Graph Explorer, one can easily get confused by the App pulldown. Please select the desired Game App and try again :-)